# jekyll bootstrap page not showing in navigation

Tags: ruby, twitter-bootstrap, jekyll, jekyll-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a page to my Jekyll Bootstrap blog and it's not showing up in the navbar. I thought that if you included the correct YAML front matter, the pages would automatically generate in the nav. I've created the page manually with a .html file extension, created the page using the command

```
rake page name="about.md"
```

... and neither one seems to work. I've restarted my server, I'm using

```
jekyll serve --force_polling
```

and I can't seem to get the page to show in my navigation ... please advise.

LINKS:

My github codebase: https://github.com/twotimes22/twotimes22.github.io
Documentation: http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your need to put your page in the navigation group by adding `group: navigation` in the front matter.

See the [page_list inclusion](https://github.com/plusjade/jekyll-bootstrap/blob/master/_includes/themes/bootstrap-3/default.html#L61) and the [Jekyll bootstrapp documentation](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/api/bootstrap-api.html#toc_14).

Edit: After watching at your repository I found a strange bug.

You have a trailing space in the front matter that the page away fronm the jekyll page listing ??

This is your front matter  :

```
---[space]
layout: page
title: "Toto"
group: navigation
---[space]
```

Removing the [space] makes the page appear in the pages list. Strange !

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the reply. I've done this and it doesn't seem to be working for me. Also, should the page have a file ext of .html or .md?